# Get only the value of row with maximum count in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the value of the row with maximum count value.

I created an output using `q['Season'].value_counts()`.

I want only the first row value and not the count.
e.g.:

```
Season Count
 2008    318
 2016    308
 2010    303
```

Output required:  2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert value counts into dataframe and call `idxmax` function. This way -

```py
q['Season'].value_counts().to_frame().idxmax()
```

Gives output -

```py
Season    2008
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

q['Season'].value_counts().idxmax()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code and by adding the output of your code you will improve the quality of your answer. Thanks